# NoReverseMatch for facebook login using dj-rest-auth

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-allauth, dj-rest-auth

I'm trying to implement social login with facebook using dj-rest-auth. When I'm trying to post access_token getting the following error

```
NoReverseMatch at /v1/auth/facebook/
Reverse for 'socialaccount_signup' not found. 'socialaccount_signup' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Here is my code:

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'core',
    'rest_framework',
    'tinymce',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'dj_rest_auth',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'dj_rest_auth.registration',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.google",
]

SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'
SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = False
SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True
```

**Views.py**

```
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook.views import FacebookOAuth2Adapter
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.google.views import GoogleOAuth2Adapter
from dj_rest_auth.registration.views import SocialLoginView


class FacebookLogin(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = FacebookOAuth2Adapter
```

**urls.py**

```
app_name = "social_app"
urlpatterns = [
    path('v1/auth/', include('dj_rest_auth.urls')),
    path('v1/auth/registration/', include('dj_rest_auth.registration.urls')),
    path('v1/auth/facebook/', FacebookLogin.as_view(), name='fb_login'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

How can I fix this NoReverseMatch issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django-rest-auth facebook NoReverseMatch:Reverse for 'socialaccount\_signup' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40956530/django-rest-auth-facebook-noreversematchreverse-for-socialaccount-signup-with)

Comment: @BrianDestura Thank you for your recommendation. But I already have seen that answer but no luck. Any other suggestion?

Comment: I've removed the app_name and working fine.